# Angular testing, using mocha, unexpected requests

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocha.js, konacha

In my angular tests I keep getting a `Error: Unexpected request: GET 'some/rails/view.html'`

I'm using konacha for testing, which uses mocha instead of jasmine. The project is based around a Rails app which is the reason for using konacha.

Here's a really simple sample test that checks if the controller is defined in the Angular app:

```
describe "ShowAccountCtrl", ->

  beforeEach angular.mock.module('APP_NAME')

  beforeEach inject(($rootScope, $controller) ->
    @scope = $rootScope.$new()
    @ctrl = $controller 'ShowAccountCtrl',
      $scope: @scope
  )


  it "should be defined", ->
    expect(@ctrl).to.not.be.undefined
```

I've seen some things about `$httpBackend.when('GET', /\.html$/).passThrough();` but konacha doesn't seem to have a similar method to `passThrough()`

These issues always happen upon a `$httpBackend.flush()`.

Has anyone conquered this problem before? Is there a way to ignore requests to rails templates so I can focus on testing functionality of the controllers?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Konacha doesn't [support any integration with Rails views](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/konacha/issues/115).  The solution is to load angular's `$templateCache` manually, similar to what you have to do when using templates [with the asset pipeline](http://minhajuddin.com/2013/04/28/angularjs-templates-and-rails-with-eager-loading).  To make this work you will need to make your test have the ERB pre-processor (e.g. `some_spec.js.coffee.erb`).

```js
beforeEach inject ($templateCache) ->    
  template = '/app/templates/view.html'
  content = """
  <%= IO.read(Rails.root.join('/app/templates/view.html')) %>
  """  
  $templateCache.put template, content
```